Ubuntu 24.04 LTS earplug audio problem
So, I recently got the idea to start using linux, as it was recommended by some of my coworkers, and I ended up installing Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, as I read it was the most user-friendly linux to start with.
Since the day I installed it, it has this audio problem where the speakers works fine, but when I plug a earplug in, the audio gets all weird (it's like a mix of low, robotic and buzzy sounds, but only when media is being reproduced)....
I've been searching for a solution for 2-3 days, and I'm honestly close to giving up on Linux because of this problem :(
Things I've found in forums and tried:

Messing with pulseaudio
Messing with alsamixer
Checking if i've installed all the core drivers for ubuntu
Installing some "oss-linux" stuff
Installing "pavucontrol" or something like that
Using "sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras"

All the forums i've found says things along these, but none of them seem to have worked for me :(
Can someone help me please? I really want to stick to ubuntu
Edit: Hardware (tell me if any more info is needed)

12th Gen Intel Core (i7-1255U)
512GB SSD (70 allocated to Ubuntu on dual boot)
16GB RAM
Integrated Intel graphics


Tag 20.04?  Some hardware information would be helpful. Do the earplugs work in another machine, under Windows, ... etc.> Do you see the earplugs as an audio output under Settings/Sound?  Check the overamplification/output level with the test button.  A clean install might be easier to get working than undoing all the changes to audio you have already made.

Oops, I tagged the wrong version
Yeah, the plugs work on other machines, and are showing up on the settings... The thing is, sound comes through them, but nothing intelligible, and I tried overamplificating them, but the buzzes just get louder :(
I'll edit the post to add some hardware info

What does messing mean? Exact info needed for an answer. Whole question full of useless info like installed stuff. Please edit the question and add some real details.

@DavidDE why so mean man
I don't rlly know what kind of info can help with the problem, as I've never done any post on forums...
I used some commands I found on some questions regarding audio, but I didn't keep track of installations...
I added the details I know, anything else needed I would like to know, so the problem could be diagnosed....
As for "messing with", sorry, english is not my primary language, and I don't know if I used the term correctly... I meant that I got in the plugin/something and changed all the setngs available, 1 by 1, all at once, etc, and it didn't do much
